# add attribute to capacitor-cordova-android-plugins ShareChooserPendingIntent receiver

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

In attempt to update the targetSdkVersion to 31 I have encountered this merge manifest error:

> Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.

The file causing this issue is `capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` at application/receiver "nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent".

```
<receiver android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent" android:enabled="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Build works fine when I manually add the attribute `android:exported="false"` to the receiver but the problem is that this file is regenerated upon sync/build.

How can I add this attribute without manually editing the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use [Capacitor CLI Hooks](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cli/hooks) to rewrite the file as seen [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/add-attribute-to-capacitor-cordova-android-plugins-sharechooserpendingintent-receiver/226469).

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "capacitor:update:after": "cd scripts/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins && CapacitorCordovaAndroidPlugins",
    "capacitor:sync:after": "cd scripts/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins && CapacitorCordovaAndroidPlugins"
}
```

CapacitorCordovaAndroidPlugins.cs:

where src is you path to the manifest file (stackoverflow was having trouble posting with that string???)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace CapacitorCordovaAndroidPlugins {
    public class App {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            string src = "";

            string content = File.ReadAllText(src);
            string pattern = @"(<receiver .*(?<!android:exported=""false""))(?=>)";
            string replacement = @"$1 android:exported=""false""";

            content = Regex.Replace(content, pattern, replacement);

            File.WriteAllText(src, content);
        }
    }
}
```